# Weird mod operator (%) result when using #define

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, modulo

```
int temp1,temp2,temp3;
temp1 = 199;
temp2 = 200;
temp3 = 199%temp2;

CString txt;
txt.Format(_T("temp3 = %d"),temp3);
AfxMessageBox(txt);
```

Output is 199 as expected.

```
#define WIDTH 100
#define BUFFERWIDTH 200
int temp1,temp2,temp3;
temp1 = 199;
temp2 = BUFFERWIDTH;
temp3 = 199%BUFFERWIDTH;

CString txt;
txt.Format(_T("temp3 = %d"),temp3);
AfxMessageBox(txt);
```

Output is 199 as expected.

```
#define WIDTH 100
#define BUFFERWIDTH 2*WIDTH
int temp1,temp2,temp3;
temp1 = 199;
temp2 = BUFFERWIDTH;
temp3 = 199%BUFFERWIDTH;

CString txt;
txt.Format(_T("temp3 = %d"),temp3);
AfxMessageBox(txt);
```

Output is 100...

Just wondering what is causing this :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Read up about [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), and note that you are saying `199 % 2 * 100`.

.
.
.

or should I say, `(199 % 2)   *   100`...

Comment: Yup. One of the most common pitfalls when using MACROS.

Comment: @Pablo: Indeed. You should always define value macros like that with parentheses... but wait, this is C++, so you shouldn't be using those ghastly monsters anyway and say `const size_t height = 2 * width;` like a grown-up!

Answer (score 4):

This is a classic problem with the preprocessor.  The issue is that when you write

```
#define BUFFERWIDTH 2*WIDTH
temp3 = 199%BUFFERWIDTH;
```

The preprocessor expands this out to

```
#define BUFFERWIDTH 2*WIDTH
temp3 = 199 % 2 * WIDTH;
```

Notice that this is interpreted as

```
temp3 = (199 % 2) * WIDTH;
```

instead of the intended

```
temp3 = 199 % (2 * WIDTH);
```

To fix this, you have multiple options.  First, you could parenthesize your definition of `BUFFERWIDTH` like this:

```
#define BUFFERWIDTH (2*WIDTH)
temp3 = 199%BUFFERWIDTH;
```

Now, this expands out to

```
temp3 = 199 % (2 * WIDTH);
```

as expected.  However, a better option would be to use `const` to define your constants:

```
const int BUFFERWIDTH = 2 * WIDTH;
temp3 = 199%BUFFERWIDTH;
```

This is now interpreted correctly, because constants are understood by the compiler rather than the preprocessor.

More generally, I *strongly* urge you not to use `#define` to define constants.  `#define` is essentially a search-and-replace mechanism over the source code that has no semantic or syntactic understanding of what it replaces.  It doesn't play well with operator precedence, and so you can easily run into bugs like this.  `const`, on the other hand, *is* understood by the compiler to define a constant, and so expressions will be evaluated correctly when operator precedence comes into play.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

One of the most common pitfalls when using MACROS is not realizing that MACROS are code replacement units. So, your code:

```
#define BUFFERWIDTH 2*WIDTH
// ...
temp3 = 199%BUFFERWIDTH;
```

After preprocessing converts to:

```
temp3 = 199%2*100;
```

If you apply operator precedence, you get the number you showed.

Answer (score 1):

In the last case,

```
temp3 = 199%BUFFERWIDTH;
```

becomes

```
temp3 = 199%2*WIDTH
```

which is

```
temp3 = 199%2*100
```

so

```
temp3 = (199%2) * 100
```

which means

```
temp3 = 100.
```

Rewrite it:

```
#define BUFFERWIDTH (2*WIDTH)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your last example, `199%BUFFERWIDTH` expands to `199 % 2 * 100` which evaluates to 100.

Answer (score 0):

The preprocessor transforms this to `199*2%200`.

Since `*` has a higher precedence than `%`, this is parsed as `(199 * 2) % 200`.

This is one of the many reasons where non-trivial `#DEFINE`s are evil.
In this particular case, you can fix it with parentheses:

```
#define BUFFERWIDTH (2*WIDTH)
```

Comment: AFAIK, % and * have the same precedence, so they are evaluated left to right: (199%2)*100 = 1*100 = 100. FWIW, (199*2)%200 would give 198.

Answer (score 0):

You fallen into the [Operator Precedence Macro Trap](http://www.ebyte.it/library/codesnippets/WritingCppMacros.html#4):

```
temp3 = 199%BUFFERWIDTH;
```

Becomes:

```
temp3 = 199%2*WIDTH;
```

Which becomes:

```
temp3 = 199%2*100;
```

Since `%` and `*` have equal precedence they are evaluated left to right and you get `temp3 = 1*100;`

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
temp3 = 199%BUFFERWIDTH;
```

resolves to

```
temp3 = 199%2*WIDTH;
```

which is not what you want. Enclose `2*WIDTH` in parentheses, and you get the desired result:

```
#define BUFFERWIDTH (2*WIDTH)
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst macros as considered evil, but there are instances where they cannot be avoided at all, and ease if programming a lot. All macros should be fully parenthesized no matter how small:

`#define BUFFERWIDTH ( 2 * (WIDTH) )`

Which would adapt any changes you make to `WIDTH` later:

`#define WITDH (10+12*55)`